# Align lightning:button with lightning:input when input validation error occurs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I am using the following lightning:layout grid to get input field and button to behave nicely:

```
<lightning:layout verticalAlign="end">
        <lightning:layoutitem padding="around-small" size="8" flexibility="auto">
            <lightning:input label="Enter Id" name="recordId" minlength="15" maxlength="18"/>
        </lightning:layoutitem>
        <lightning:layoutitem padding="around-small" size="4" flexibility="auto">            
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" title="Click to retrieve fields" label="Retrieve" type="Submit" iconName="utility:search" iconPosition="left" onclick="" />
        </lightning:layoutitem>
    </lightning:layout>
```

All looks pretty:

[image: Pretty version]

Until the validation pops up and the buttons gets displaced:

[image: Displaced button]

How would I get this sorted out without using too much custom CSS if any? Maybe even using `lightning:layout` alone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My advice, try to use the native css classes, you just need to add

slds-form slds-form_horizontal

wrapping everything in it

```
<lightning:layout verticalAlign="end" class="slds-form slds-form_horizontal">
    <lightning:layoutitem padding="around-small" size="8" flexibility="auto">
        <lightning:input label="Enter Id" name="recordId" minlength="15" maxlength="18"/>
    </lightning:layoutitem>
    <lightning:layoutitem padding="around-small" size="4" flexibility="auto">            
        <lightning:button variant="neutral" title="Click to retrieve fields" label="Retrieve" type="Submit" iconName="utility:search" iconPosition="left" onclick="" />
    </lightning:layoutitem>
</lightning:layout>
```

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/#Form-Label

Comment: Trying to make this work in LWC. It doesn't work even if I wrap everything inside. layout and layout item with form classes.
https://jsfiddle.net/vem728uy/

Answer (score 1):

add a css class to the first lightning layout item and give it a height of 78px

Comment: Would that height be valid across all devices?

Comment: Yep would work. you can try the same using responsive testing in the browser. I used chrome to test it

Comment: Did try. Cannot accept it as best answer since the 78px will only be valid for layout:items with padding around-small.  :/

Comment: i will give you a solution which will work for both cases in sometime